# How to treat a combobox as a link to another form?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I've been struggling with trying to modify a combobox to treat the currently selected item as a link to another form.

The basic workflow is simple; I want the text in a combobox to function like a link when not selecting a new item from the list.  This link will open a new form, and find the relevant record.  ie. click on the customer name to open the Customer form and show their info.

The problem is specific to the combobox; the same functionality works just fine for a textbox.  Put the code in the Click event, form opens, goes to the right record, easy peasy.  I should be able to just do the same thing with a combobox, right?

Nope.  The Click event on the Combobox [only fires when selecting a new item from the list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/combobox-click-event-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  It says, `Clicks a control with the left mouse button. Clicking a control with the right or middle mouse button does not trigger this event.`, but it doesn't do anything when clicking.

Alright.  Let's set it as a hyperlink.  That should fire the Click event!  Nope.  It first tries to follow the, "link", and since the value is an internal primary key, it doesn't know what to do with it.  So it errors, and goes nowhere.

Now my attempts get more esoteric.  Let's hide a rectangle behind the combobox, and put the code in it's Click event!  Nope.  Doesn't flow through to the object behind.  Let's just put it on top of the dropdown!  Nope.  Still doesn't fire the rectangle's Click event.

Okay, get rid of the rectangle.  Let's try putting the code in the MouseUp event of the Combobox.  Bingo.  Clicking the text works now.  But...now it does it every time I click on it.  I don't want it opening the form when I'm trying to select another customer.

I've tried [detecting when the dropdown is expanded](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0052.htm), and not following the link when it returns true.  That...sort of works.  It won't close the expanded dropdown now, and you can't debug it, because the detection code is low level and showing the debug screen makes it return false (because the dropdown isn't open anymore).

I've tried setting a static variable to only follow the link when not selecting a new item.  That's super inconsistent, as there's no good way to figure out what state the combobox is in.

Turning text into a clickable link shouldn't be this hard.  How can I make the currently selected item in a combobox a link, while not making everything else in the combobox a link at the same time?  Am I missing an event or something?

Comment: Trying to follow what you're trying to do and it hoping you can enlighten. How do you expect to determine if user just wants to click or expand the list when they click on the combo box? That is how do you know that they want to use the current customer or select a  new one?

Comment: Sure thing - works great - please mark as answer if it works or upvote any comments or answers to your posts that help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have a solution that will work for you as I understand what you're trying to do.

To setup the form overlay a text box (I used `Text3`) on top of your combo box (I used `Combo0`) drop down area leaving the down arrow visible.

In addition I set Text Box properties for `Shape Outline` color so I could visibly tell if it was working. For the Combo Box - I also clicked on `Arrange` - to `Send To Back` so it would be hidden behind the text box.

Whenever the ComboBox is changed (by clicking its arrow) it also sets the value of the textBox - which can be set to Hyperlink if you want

**1. Text box is displayed but combo box arrow is visible**

[image: Text Box Default]

**2. Combo Box arrow has been clicked to show dropdown**

[image: Combo Box Arrow]

**3. Clicking Text Box is will generate code in Click Event or Hyperlink**

[image: Clicked on text box]

**Example Form VBA**

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print "Updated"
    Text3 = Combo0.Value
    Text3.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Combo0_Click()
    Debug.Print "Clicked"
    Text3.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Combo0_Enter()
    Debug.Print "Enter: " & Combo0
    Text3.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Text3 = Combo0.Value
    Text3.Visible = True
    Text3.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't thought of putting a text box on top.  I'll have to try that and see how it works.

Comment: Let us know how the testing goes

Comment: My testing shows this will work.  It's unfortunate that comboboxes can't do this out of the box, but whatever works, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I ran a quick test, and this worked as expected for me:

```
Private Sub Combo14_Click()

Select Case Combo14
    Case Is = "Form1"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
    Case Is = "Form2"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2"
    Case Is = "Form3"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3"
    Case Is = "Form4"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form4"
End Select

End Sub
```

Edit:

Try this as well then, in the GotFocus event field.

```
Private Sub Combo14_GotFocus()

Select Case Combo14
    Case Is = "Form1"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
    Case Is = "Form2"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2"
    Case Is = "Form3"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3"
    Case Is = "Form4"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form4"
End Select

End Sub
```

Note: You'll want to move focus to something else at the end of the sub.

Comment: This is when you're *selecting* an item.  I want it to work on the item already selected, without expanding the dropdown.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: This will also happen when expanding the listbox.  Please read my question fully; I want the link to only work when clicking on the actual text of the combobox.